# Delphi 7 object undefinedat

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tadoquery, adoconnection

I have a web service that I have created using Delphi and I want to connect to sql server with it so I have added to the project an ADO Connection and ADOQuery had both of them configured and ready to use, there was only a small problem, there are two units on my project and those objects were added to Unit1 and I am working with my ImplUnit whitch is another unit, and can`t find a way to reference or include one unit inside the other unit.

unit1

```
  { SOAP WebModule} 
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, HTTPApp, InvokeRegistry, WSDLIntf, TypInfo,
  WebServExp, WSDLBind, XMLSchema, WSDLPub, SOAPPasInv, SOAPHTTPPasInv,
  SOAPHTTPDisp, WebBrokerSOAP, DB, ADODB;

type
  TWebModule1 = class(TWebModule)
    HTTPSoapDispatcher1: THTTPSoapDispatcher;
    HTTPSoapPascalInvoker1: THTTPSoapPascalInvoker;
    WSDLHTMLPublish1: TWSDLHTMLPublish;
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADODataSet1: TADODataSet;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    procedure WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
      Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  WebModule1: TWebModule1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  WSDLHTMLPublish1.ServiceInfo(Sender, Request, Response, Handled);
end;

end.
```

My unit

```
   unit UTImplementacao;

interface

uses
  InvokeRegistry,DB, ADODB;


type
    IInterface = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{EFF30FFA-DA0C-433A-832A-0BA057B55103}']
    function ReceiveUser(username : String; password : String) :
    Boolean; stdcall;
  end;



  TImplementacao = class(TInvokableClass, IInterface)
    public
    function ReceiveUser(username : String; password : String) :
    Boolean; stdcall;
   end;

implementation

{ TImplementacao }

function TImplementacao.ReceiveUser(username, password: String): Boolean;
var
 ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
 ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
begin
    try
      ADOConnection1 := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
      ADOConnection1.LoginPrompt := False;
      ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:= 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;' +
                                        'Persist Security Info=False;' +
                                        'User ID=Diego;'+
                                        'Catalog=OnlineShopping;' +
                                        'Data Source=DIEGO-PC\SQLEXPRESS'+
                                        ';Use Procedure for Prepare=1;' +
                                        'Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;'+
                                        'Workstation ID=DIEGO-PC;'+
                                        'Use Encryption for Data=False;'+
                                        'Tag with column collation when possible=False;';
      ADOConnection1.Connected := True;
      ADOQuery1.Connection := ADOConnection1;
      ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select username,upassword from Users '+
                      'where  username = :usernamep and upassword = '+
                      ':upasswordp');
      ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('upasswordp').Value := password;
      ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('usernamep').Value  := username;
      ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

      Result := True;

finally
  ADOQuery1.Free;
  if ADOConnection1.Connected then
    ADOConnection1.Close;
    ADOConnection1.Free;
  end;


 Result := False;

end;

initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokableClass(TImplementacao);
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IInterface));

end.
```

please disregard the ADOConnection and ADOQuery that I have added to my unit i got a little desperate ad duplicade the code...  Yeah, I know yachs!!!!

@SilverWarrior

If declare Unit1 inside the uses of UTImplementacao will I have access to the componemts below:

```
type
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
        ADODataSet1: TADODataSet;
        ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
```

or should I declare for each one of the types variable inside var clause ?

Comment: Either you didn't post the actual code you're using, or you need to pay more attention to your screen. You have an badly terminated comment in the first of these files. SO makes this easy to see in the question, also in the preview. The Delphi IDE also makes this easy to see the same way. Anyway, even aside from that, it's pretty much impossible for me to figure out what you're trying to ask. Take a step back, look at your own question, and see if you would be able to understand it if someone else had asked it. If not, you can fix up the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but to make it simple, I want to create a web service that will connect to sql server database using Delphi.

Comment: This is not your real code, because both units are named `unit1`, and you can't have two units of the same name in the same project. When you get around to providing the actual code you're having problems with, and can *clearly explain* the problem you're having, [edit] your question and do so. Until then, I'm voting to close it as off-topic because you've not clearly stated the problem or included the relevant code.

Comment: @KenWhite It seems that OP made a mistake and posted same code from unit1 for both units.

Comment: sorry... Now I have copied the right code

Comment: @user2414726 Let me see if I understand your final goal here. You basically want to move all the ADO code from your MyUnit into Unit1 and use it from there. Right?

Comment: Actually in Unit1 I already have all the components to access the database as you can see in uses and type clauses, what I want is to use those objects inside MyUnit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access objects declared in Unit1 from other units in your project you need to add Unit1 into interface uses section (the one at top) of those units.

```
unit ImplUnit;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, ... , Unit1;

...
```

That is the same way as Delphi automatically adds other units like Sysutils, Classes, etc.

Also I would strongly recomend you change the name of your unit to somethng more meaningfull so that when you will be looking at your code after some time you will quickly know what code does that unit contains and what it is used for.

EDIT: Based on your edit of the question I suspect you want to acces the components from your Unit1 directly by calling:

```
Unit1.AdoConnection1
```

That won't work. Why? Becouse the components are declared within the scope of the `TWebModule1` class.

So you need to access them like this:

```
Unit1.WebModule1.AdoConnection1;
```

NOTE: If Unit1 is added into interface uses section of your UTImplementacao unit you can also directly call:

```
WebModule1.AdoConnection1
```

You don't have to prefix every command with Unit1. I have written this in such way to be hopefully more understandable which unit mebers are you accessing. Especially for other people which might be reading this thread and not knowing the structure of your program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did that and still i couldn`t use the objects inside unit1.